# Rounding time in PHP after decimal

Tags: php, time, rounding

```
$time_taken = 286;

$time_taken = $time_taken / 60;  //Converting to minutes

echo $time_taken;
```

> Result: ***4.7666666666667***

But I need: (expectation:)

> Result: ***5.17*** (Expected)

I tried: `round($time_taken,2);`

But then it gave the result:

> Result: ***4.77***

Comment: what... your expected result is wrong ... 28615 ÷ 60 = 476.916666667

Comment: I get 476.91666666667...

Comment: Sorry, typo error it's, **286** @treyBake

Comment: @namo in that case... 286 / 60 = 4.7667 - where are you getting the 5.17 from?

Comment: That's my expected;, 4.7667 minutes doesn't make sense, so it should be 5.17 minutes @treyBake

Comment: @namo Random numbers don't make sense. How do you get that number?

Comment: You get that result because you get 4.76 minutes, which is not the same as 4 minutes and 76 seconds. It's 4 min and 0.75 of a minute. Break it down: 4 minutes = 240 sec. 286 - 240 = 46. So the result should be 4 min and 46 sec.

Comment: @namo but why is it your expected?

Comment: @treyBake - I guess the OP thought 4.7667 meant 4 minutes and 76.6..7 seconds (which, with rounding would be 5.17).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ah that makes more sense .. ty

Comment: Yes, @MagnusEriksson I thought the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the result wrong. But don't worry. Working with time have driven most devs crazy one time or another. It's like a rite of passage.

You get `4.76 minutes`, which is *not* the same as `4 minutes and 76 seconds`.

It's `4 full minutes and 0.76 of a minute`.

Break it down:

- `4 minutes = 240 sec`
- `286 - 240 = 46`

So the result should be 4 min and 46 sec.

To calculate it, you can do this:

```
$total = 286;

// Floor the minutes so we only get full minutes
$mins  = floor($total / 60);

// Calculate how many secs are left
$secs  = $total % 60; // Thanks @RiggsFolly for the tip

echo "$mins minutes and $secs seconds";
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/JA2l8c)

Comment: Hi, could simplify by doing `$secs = $total % 60;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I was about to add that if someone knows a better way, just let me know :-) I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just different :)

Comment: One line and simplest: `$time_taken = floor($time_taken/60) . ":" . $time_taken % 60;`.